# Using StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase to ignore Case

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, lambda

This code is case sensitive, how to make it case insensitive?

```
return HeaderNames.Length == fileLine.Count &&
  HeaderNames
    .Select(headItem => fileLine[Array.IndexOf(HeaderNames, headItem)] == headItem)
    .All(i => i);
```

Thanks for your answers/

Comment: You question is very unclear. Please explain better you question.

Comment: What I am looking for make this with ToUpper or to Lowoer or not case sensitive.

Comment: This code is case sensitive, how to make it case insensitive?

Comment: What is the case of entries in HeaderNames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `FindIndex` instead of `IndexOf`. 
I assume you have `array` of `strings`

```
Array.FindIndex(HeaderNames, t => t.IndexOf(headItem, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >=0);
```

**Example**:

```
var a = new string[]{"green","red"};

var idx = Array.FindIndex(a, t => t.IndexOf("Red", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >=0);

Console.WriteLine(idx);
```

**Output**

> 1

Note: You could also use `string.Equals` instead of `t.IndexOf` in above suggestion

```
t=>string.Equals(t, headItem, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

It will be a long nested `LINQ` though.

Edit

> If you want to find exact string  i.e. dont want to get index of «**ed**» from «**Red**» as item existing in array. Use string.Equals.

Comment: `t.IndexOf("ed",...` will be `>= 0` so "red" will match "ed" which is not equivalent to a case-ignoring `==`.

Comment: For that string.Equals should be used. Suggested in answer @NetMage

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to index back into the array to get the position, there is a version of `Select` for that. You can use `String.Equals` and pass the `StringComparison` option:

```
return HeaderNames.Length == fileLine.Count &&
       HeaderNames.Select((headItem, i) => fileLine[i].Equals(headItem, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).All(i => i);
```